# 404 when I try to open the site from the machine where Azure web role is deployed

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, azure

At the end of `RoleEntryPoint.OnStart()` I want to open the web role site to ensure that it doesn't break with some stupid error. So I do the following:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create( "http://127.0.0.1" );
using( WebResponse response = request.GetResponse() ) {
}
```

and this fails with `WebException` with `(404) Not Found` text. The role has an open HTTP endpoint on port 80, so this should not be a problem. However if I omit that code and the role starts I can open `http://mysubdomain.cloudpapp.net` no problem.

What's the deal here? How do I open the web page of the web role site from within the web role?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shall not use 127.0.0.1, but instead the InputEndpoint specified for the WebRole.

You can get the IPEndpoint instance from it with sode like:

```
RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.InstanceEndpoints["YourInputEndpointForWebRole"].IPEndpoint
```

Then get the [IP Address](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipendpoint.address.aspx) from the [IPEndpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipendpoint.aspx) instace.

**EDIT**

Just double checked to confirm the reason:

The reason for that is that the Site Bindings for the WebSite in IIS are not *:80 (like some nomrally do in local IIS) but just to the specific DIP (Direct (internal) IP Address) of the Instance.

Comment: Do you have any idea why it is configured that way?

Comment: Nope. But from security's prospective I would not use * bindings in my IIS, but to the specific IP address I want the site to be bound. And Windows Azure is a Cloud Operating system, designed to be self maintainable, self-healing, self monitoring platform and fully automated platform. I think the point here is to minimize chances for errors and misconfigurations.